# TeXbook Exercise 14.32

Tags: tex-core, hyphenation, plain-tex

In the end of Chapter14 of TeXbook, there is a macro called `\signed`:

```
\def\signed #1 (#2){{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\sl#1\/ \rm(#2)
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}
```

which is used to add the reviewer's name and address in the end of the review. And the `\finalhyphendemerits=0` is used to prevent TeX from preferring two final lines to one final line.

I'm still quite confused about the functional of `\finalhyphendemerits` here. Does setting `\finalhyphendemerits` always help to make more white space to the last line?

Can someone give more explanations (better with an example) please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Left with penalty set to 0 right with default]

It is really just that simple: adds extra penalty if the second last line ends with a hyphen.

The left is `\finalhyphendemerits=0`, right is with the default `5000`.

```
\hsize=2.9in
\finalhyphendemerits=0
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing
pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete
account of the system.
\bye
```

Cite TeX by Topic

> `\finalhyphendemerits` Penalty added when the penultimate line of a paragraph ends with a
> hyphen. Plain TEX default: 5000.

Note that in The TeXbook it says:

> The one-line solution will usually be preferred if it is feasible.

Setting `\finalhyphendemerits=0` helps the second last line to be more compact, making more space to the last line, thus makes the one-line version much likely to occur.

Comment: Does setting `\finalhyphendemerits=0` make more space to the last line in all cases?

Comment: @Stephen no, usually no difference (as no hyphen anyway) or it can make more or less space depending if  hyphen is avoided by squeezing the word in to the penultmate line or taking the word over to the last line

Comment: I don't know what TeX by topic says, but the unit of `\finalhyphendemerit` is not TeX-penalty, but it is penalty square, marked as "demerit" in TeXbook.

Comment: @Stephen no, it really depends on the text content, and current width to see when finalhypendemerit would make a difference

Comment: @wipet penalties (and demerits) are just integers, although the formula does square penalty to compute demerit per line before add the extra demerit parameters, the choice of taking squares is only justified by practice, so TeX by Topics doesn’t trying to make a difference from the demerit and penalty other than stating penalty needs to be squared to have same weight as demerit

Comment: So, as you have said that setting `\finalhyphendemerits=0` does not always try to make more space for the last line. Why do we need to set it here?@LdBeth

Comment: @Stephen it does always try to make more space by contributing to line breaking calculation, it is just the effect is not always visible if compared to the version not setting the finalhyphendemerits.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

In a normal paragraph, with a short last line, a hyphen on the penultimate line appears as the last thing at the right margin and just has white space below it. This is normally discouraged by `\finalhyphendemerits`.

Here, the white space in the last line does not apply as the last line is always flush to the margin as seen by the extra example added.  Worse if you do force a linebreak to avoid hypenation being on the penultmate line, you can have the opposite of the desired effect and force white space below the hyphen as seen here if the example is repeated without setting `\finalhyphendemerits` to zero.

```
\def\signed #1 (#2){{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
  \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\sl#1\/ \rm(#2)
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}

\hbox{\vrule
\vbox{\hsize 3.6in \parindent0pt
  This is a case where the name and address fit in nicely with the review.
  \signed A. Reviewer (Ann Arbor, Mich.)
  \medskip
  But sometimes an extra line must be added. \signed N. Bourbaki (Paris)
  \medskip
  This is a case where the name and address fit most excellently with the review.
  \signed A. Reviewer (Ann Arbor, Mich.)
}\vrule}

\bigskip

\def\signed #1 (#2){{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
  \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\sl#1\/ \rm(#2)
  \parfillskip=0pt \endgraf}}

\hbox{\vrule
\vbox{\hsize 3.6in \parindent0pt
  This is a case where the name and address fit in nicely with the review.
  \signed A. Reviewer (Ann Arbor, Mich.)
  \medskip
  But sometimes an extra line must be added. \signed N. Bourbaki (Paris)
  \medskip
  This is a case where the name and address fit most excellently with the review.
  \signed A. Reviewer (Ann Arbor, Mich.)
}\vrule}

\bye
```